# Why does the accounting format lose most of its properties?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The accounting format of =TEXT(E15,"*($* #,##0.00*);[Red] $* (#,##0.00);;*(@*))" equals $(62,519.00).

A) It has lost the color of being red when it is negative.

B) It has lost the dollar sign $, being on the far left of the cell.

Is there a way that I can retain those 2?

Comment: No, you can't apply those with the TEXT function. Why do you need to use it?

Comment: But I can apply =TEXT(E15,"_($* #,##0.00_);[Red] $* (#,##0.00);;_(@_))").  it works… But it is just not in the proper format.  Do you know why the format is lost?  Specifically A & B?

Comment: Why are you using the TEXT function instead of just applying accounting format to the cell directly? As mentioned previously, you're not going to get what you want with the TEXT function.

Comment: As I said, you can't apply **those** formats. You can't change font formatting for part of a formula result.

Comment: It has already been said by @Rory sir, you cant apply a rich text formatting in a formula i.e.  the format codes for color only work within the **Format Cells** dialog box, not within a **formula**. Read **[MSFT_Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)** you can change the formatting to show numbers as **Text** or **Symbols** but not color formatting.

Comment: Thank you sirs for your answers… But Rory and BigBen didn't did not supply me with adequate answers.

It was only Mayukh Bhattacharya that gave documentation so I can read further and that had the two did the same… it would have resulted in a one line reply…

Thank you sirs…

Answer (score 0):

To retain the color and the dollar sign placement as described, you cannot achieve this directly through the TEXT function in Excel, as it converts numbers to text and does not support formatting elements like text color or specific alignments within cells. Instead, you should apply cell formatting directly:

**1. For the color:** Use Conditional Formatting to change the font color to red for negative numbers.

**2. For the dollar sign:** Apply a custom number format directly to the cell through the Format Cells dialog (Ctrl+1), using `"($* #,##0.00);[Red]($* #,##0.00);;(@)"` for the format code.

This approach allows negative numbers to appear in red and retains the dollar sign on the far left of the cell, while still displaying the value in the accounting format.

Comment: I have a summit information to send you, but it is not in the proper format.  I have 6 snips using the Snipping Tool  along with text that I wish to send over to you.  How could I send that to you?